# Spring Boot JPA though Hibernate with MYSQL8 is not executing as batches

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

**There are similar questions here on StackOverflow, however those are generic answers not specific to this setup mentioned in the question.**

Is there a way to get batch insert working in Spring Boot JPA with Hibernate on a mysql8 DB?

Even though following properties is set in application properties file; from the mysql log it is visible that insert to [customerjpa ] table happens only as a single transaction but not a batch.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

However batch insert through pure JDBC works as expected. Here inset to [customersJDBCCheck] is such.

```
2018-10-15T15:06:57.056430Z       240 Query     DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS customersJDBCCheck
2018-10-15T15:06:57.083438Z       240 Query     select @@session.transaction_read_only
2018-10-15T15:06:57.084438Z       240 Query     CREATE TABLE customersJDBCCheck(id SERIAL, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255))
2018-10-15T15:06:57.394531Z       240 Query     select @@session.transaction_read_only
2018-10-15T15:06:57.396532Z       240 Query     INSERT INTO customersJDBCCheck(first_name, last_name) VALUES ('John','Woo'),('Jeff','Dean'),('Josh','Bloch'),('Josh','Long')
2018-10-15T15:06:57.434543Z       240 Query     SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customersJDBCCheck WHERE first_name = 'Josh'
2018-10-15T15:06:57.444546Z       240 Query     select @@session.transaction_read_only
2018-10-15T15:06:57.446547Z       240 Query     DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS customersJDBCCheck
2018-10-15T15:06:57.585589Z       240 Query     SET autocommit=0
2018-10-15T15:06:57.636604Z       240 Query     insert into customerjpa (first_name, last_name) values ('Jack', 'Bauer')
2018-10-15T15:06:57.661612Z       240 Query     insert into customerjpa (first_name, last_name) values ('Chloe', 'O\'Brian')
2018-10-15T15:06:57.678617Z       240 Query     insert into customerjpa (first_name, last_name) values ('Kim', 'Bauer')
2018-10-15T15:06:57.688620Z       240 Query     insert into customerjpa (first_name, last_name) values ('Michelle', 'Dessler')
2018-10-15T15:06:57.710626Z       240 Query     commit
2018-10-15T15:06:57.710626Z       240 Query     SET autocommit=1
```

Entity class

```
@Entity
class CustomerJPA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected CustomerJPA() {
    }

    public CustomerJPA(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using identifier of type GenerationType.**SEQUENCE** with pooled-lo optimizer is the solution here.

Details of the analysis as following.

Main point here is that Hibernate disables insert batching at the JDBC level transparently if you use an **IDENTITY** identifier generator. (Ref: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html )

Once it is changed to @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.**SEQUENCE**) much more inefficient as there are multiple selects and updates for the sequence.
However insert statement executes as a batch query.
Behind the scene this creates table as following.

```
2018-10-16T12:15:07.125581Z       561 Query     create table customerjpa (
       id bigint not null,
        first_name varchar(255),
        last_name varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    ) engine=InnoDB
2018-10-16T12:15:07.301581Z       561 Query     SHOW WARNINGS
2018-10-16T12:15:07.302581Z       561 Query     select @@session.transaction_read_only
2018-10-16T12:15:07.303581Z       561 Query     create table hibernate_sequence (
       next_val bigint
    ) engine=InnoDB
```

Log of getting Id values and executing batch update.

```
2018-10-16T08:58:56.016432Z       393 Query     select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
2018-10-16T08:58:56.020432Z       393 Query     update hibernate_sequence set next_val= 41 where next_val=40
2018-10-16T08:58:56.037432Z       393 Query     commit
2018-10-16T08:58:56.038432Z       393 Query     SET autocommit=1
2018-10-16T08:58:56.059432Z       393 Query     SET autocommit=0
2018-10-16T08:58:56.060432Z       393 Query     select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
2018-10-16T08:58:56.061432Z       393 Query     update hibernate_sequence set next_val= 42 where next_val=41
2018-10-16T08:58:56.074432Z       393 Query     commit
2018-10-16T08:58:56.075432Z       393 Query     SET autocommit=1
2018-10-16T08:58:56.076432Z       393 Query     SET autocommit=0
2018-10-16T08:58:56.077432Z       393 Query     select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
2018-10-16T08:58:56.078432Z       393 Query     update hibernate_sequence set next_val= 43 where next_val=42
2018-10-16T08:58:56.085432Z       393 Query     commit
2018-10-16T08:58:56.086432Z       393 Query     SET autocommit=1
2018-10-16T08:58:56.086432Z       393 Query     SET autocommit=0
2018-10-16T08:58:56.087432Z       393 Query     select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
2018-10-16T08:58:56.088432Z       393 Query     update hibernate_sequence set next_val= 44 where next_val=43
2018-10-16T08:58:56.093432Z       393 Query     commit
2018-10-16T08:58:56.093432Z       393 Query     SET autocommit=1
2018-10-16T08:58:56.128432Z       392 Query     select @@session.transaction_read_only
2018-10-16T08:58:56.129432Z       392 Query     insert into customerjpa (first_name, last_name, id) values ('Jack', 'Bauer', 40),('Chloe', 'O\'Brian', 41),('Kim', 'Bauer', 42),('Michelle', 'Dessler', 43)
2018-10-16T08:58:56.140432Z       392 Query     commit
2018-10-16T08:58:56.141432Z       392 Query     SET autocommit=1
```

Even though that creates a batch update Id generation is not optimal. It can be optimized with pooled-lo optimizer (Ref:https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-hidden-gem-the-pooled-lo-optimizer/)

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "sequenceGenerator",
        strategy = "enhanced-sequence",
        parameters = {
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                        name = "optimizer",
                        value = "pooled-lo"
                ),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                        name = "initial_value",
                        value = "1"
                ),
                @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                        name = "increment_size",
                        value = "10"
                )
        }
)
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "sequenceGenerator"
)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true,updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

Optimized batch insert can be seen in the log as following.

```
2018-10-16T12:15:10.076581Z       564 Query     SET autocommit=0
2018-10-16T12:15:10.084581Z       564 Query     select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update
2018-10-16T12:15:10.086581Z       564 Query     update hibernate_sequence set next_val= 11 where next_val=1
2018-10-16T12:15:10.087581Z       564 Query     commit
2018-10-16T12:15:10.106581Z       564 Query     SET autocommit=1
2018-10-16T12:15:10.164581Z       563 Query     select @@session.transaction_read_only
2018-10-16T12:15:10.165581Z       563 Query     insert into customerjpa (first_name, last_name, id) values ('Jack', 'Bauer', 1),('Chloe', 'O\'Brian', 2),('Kim', 'Bauer', 3),('Michelle', 'Dessler', 4)
2018-10-16T12:15:10.169581Z       563 Query     commit
```